# Draggables Jquery UI with start & stop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Read the doc on JQuery UI's & I am using draggable() function from this plugin & I am able to drag & drop a div.

But now I want to drag a thumbnail (#b1) & on my drop my div (#d) should appear.
I got to know there is an currentTarget in event which is calling the thumbnail.
What I know is I have to change

```
 var objArr = new Array();

  $(function() {    
  $( "#b1" ).draggable({
  start: function(event, ui) {

  },
  stop: function(event, ui) {

        $(".box").append('<div id="box'+objArr.length+'" class="border" onclick="$(this).resizable();$(this).draggable();"><img src="close.png" alt="close" width="20" height="20" class="close" id=box"'+objArr.length+'" onclick="$(this).parent().hide();">  <textarea rows="2" class="txt" id="TextBox'+objArr.length+'" cols="2"></textarea></div>');          
        var tmpObj = $("#box"+objArr.length)
        tmpObj.offset().top = event.clientY
        tmpObj.offset().left = event.clientX
        objArr.push(tmpObj)

  }
});
```

How to do that I don't know.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of what you want to do:
**JQuery**

```
$("#one").data("fullImageSrc", "http://cdn.asriran.com/files/fa/news/1389/10/27/162857_203.jpg");
$("#two").data("fullImageSrc", "http://far30.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/03.jpg");
$(".draggable").draggable({
    cursor: "crosshair",
    revert: "invalid"
});
$("#drop").droppable({
    accept: ".draggable",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        console.log("drop");
        $(this).removeClass("border").removeClass("over");
        var dropped = ui.draggable;
        var droppedOn = $(this);
        var fullImageUrl = $(dropped).data("fullImageSrc");
        var imgSrc = $(dropped).attr("src");
        $(dropped).detach().css({
            top: 0,
            left: 0
        }).hide().attr("src", fullImageUrl).data("fullImageSrc", imgSrc).load(function () {
            $(this).show();
        }).appendTo(droppedOn);
    },
    over: function (event, elem) {
        $(this).addClass("over");
        console.log("over");
    },
    out: function (event, elem) {
        $(this).removeClass("over");
    }
});
$("#drop").sortable();
$("#origin").droppable({
    accept: ".draggable",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        console.log("drop");
        $(this).removeClass("border").removeClass("over");
        var dropped = ui.draggable;
        var droppedOn = $(this);
        var fullImageUrl = $(dropped).data("fullImageSrc");
        var imgSrc = $(dropped).attr("src");
        $(dropped).detach().css({
            top: 0,
            left: 0
        }).hide().load(function () {
            $(this).show();
        }).attr("src", fullImageUrl).data("fullImageSrc", imgSrc).appendTo(droppedOn);
    }
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/q86sx0n5/1/)

Comment: Its a nice try but I am not sure it will work for me or not.Can you  help me in my code.TIA :)

Comment: Only once it should be drag from thumbnail to img after that img should be draggable & droppable, no need to again convert it to thumbnail

Comment: thanks.It will be more to ask, but may be you know the way how could i will be able to make my thumbnail should come back to its position after dragging it & getting an image.

Comment: Remove ``$("#drop").sortable();`` and in ``drag`` function you can get element position ``var offset = $(this).offset();`` use it and move to target.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$("[myThumbnail]").draggable({

    start:function(event, ui){
        // get thumbnail
        var myThumbnail = $(this);
    },
    stop:function(event, ui){
        // get div
        // cannot!!!
    }

});

$( "[myDiv]" ).droppable({

  drop: function(event, ui) {
      var myThumbnail = ui.draggable;
  }

});
```

Comment: I want to know how to get thumbnail & get div.It won't work though.Its gud way to explain But not the way for coding.Thanks.